# Why does my minimax algorithm not work properly?

Tags: c, recursion, minimax

I've made an algorithm that finds the largest number in a binary tree:
(I know I should call the function "max" instead of "minimax", but It's too tedious to change it-)

I create a struct for every node and then link them together through the left and right pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Struct for every node:
typedef struct treenode
{
    int value;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
} treenode;

// Prototypes:
treenode *createNode(int value);
treenode *minimax(treenode *root);

int main()
{
    // Create the nodes:
    treenode *n1 = createNode(0);
    treenode *n2 = createNode(2);
    treenode *n3 = createNode(3);
    treenode *n4 = createNode(200);
    treenode *n5 = createNode(5);
    treenode *n6 = createNode(102);
    treenode *n7 = createNode(101);
    treenode *n8 = createNode(999);
    treenode *n9 = createNode(888);

    // Link them together:
    n1->left = n2;
    n1->right = n3;
    n3->left = n4;
    n3->right = n5;
    n5->left = n6;
    n5->right = n7;
    n7->left = n8;
    n7->right = n9;

    // Print the output of minimax():
    printf("%d", minimax(n1)->value);

    // Free the nodes:
    free(n1);
    free(n2);
    free(n3);
    free(n4);
    free(n5);
    free(n6);
    free(n7);
    free(n8);
    free(n9);
    return 0;
}

// Creates a new node in the tree, that isn't linked to anything:
treenode *createNode(int value)
{
    treenode *result = malloc(sizeof(treenode));
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        result->left = NULL;
        result->right = NULL;
        result->value = value;
    }
    return result;
}

// The minimax() function is recursive:
treenode *minimax(treenode *root)
{
    // If there are no "children" linked with the current node, return the current node:
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return root;
    // If there is only one child linked, minimax() this child and return the biggest value in it:
    if (root->left == NULL)
        return minimax(root->right);
    if (root->right == NULL)
        return minimax(root->left);
    // If the biggest value in the left child is greater than the biggest value in the right child, return the left child:
    if (minimax(root->left)->value > minimax(root->right)->value)
        return root->left;
    // If the biggest value in the right child is greater than the biggest value in the left child, return the right child:
    if (minimax(root->right)->value > minimax(root->left)->value)
        return root->left;
    // If the biggest values in both children are equal, return the left one:
    if (minimax(root->right)->value == minimax(root->left)->value)
        return root->left;
}
```

The program printed "2" instead of "999", not like I expected, but I can't find the error...

Comment: Are you claiming every step of the program's execution is correct, except the result printed is still wrong?

Comment: You are returning `root->left` instead of `minimax(root->left)`, but to avoid extra function calls, you should save the return values of `minimax(root->left)` and `minimax(root->right)` in local variables.

Comment: @ScottHunter No, I think there's something wrong with my minimax() function

Comment: @IanAbbott But that just improves speed and not the function itself right?

Comment: Yes, your algorithm is wrong. Try to draw the tree you create and then step the code while looking at the tree

Comment: "But that just improves speed and not the function itself right?" No, it affects the return value too. And one of your `return root->left;` statements should have been a `return root->right;` although that is also wrong in the same way that `return root->left;` is wrong.

Comment: Are you claiming every step of your minimax function's execution is correct, but the result printed is still wrong?

Comment: `if (minimax(root->right)->value == minimax(root->left)->value)` That last check is useless. If you come here, it must be true unless you modified your tree in between your calls. With that said, you can combine it with the `if` above and just use `else return root->left;`

Comment: Where do you compare the value of the root node to the values of the children?

Comment: Hint: Make it more simple: `treenode *n1 = createNode(1000);
    treenode *n2 = createNode(2);
    treenode *n3 = createNode(3);

    // Link them together:
    n1->left = n2;
    n1->right = n3;` What is the max value? What will your program say?

Comment: @IanAbbott But why would I store the return values in local variables if I only ever check each node once?

Comment: @Gerhardh Good point! It doesn't affect the final outcome though, it only increases the speed

Comment: @SupportUkraine It now says "3"...

Comment: @PilkeySEK yes... but it should say 1000. See my answer.

Comment: Re “But why would I store the return values in local variables if I only ever check each node once?”: Because your code calls `minimax` on the subtrees multiple times. When it evaluates `minimax(root->left)->value > minimax(root->right)->value` and then `minimax(root->right)->value > minimax(root->left)->value`, it processes both subtrees twice. In some cases, that means the leaf nodes will be examined twice, and then the next nodes up will be examined four times, and the nodes up from that eight times, and so on. It is hugely inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value could be stored in the root or anywhere in the left or right branches.

```
treenode *minimax(treenode *root)
{
    treenode *ret = root;
    treenode *temp;

    if (root)
    {
        temp = minimax(root->left);
        if (temp && temp->value > ret->value)
        {
            ret = temp;
        }
        temp = minimax(root->right);
        if (temp && temp->value > ret->value)
        {
            ret = temp;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is that you (sometimes) ignore the value of the current/root node.

Consider this:

```
treenode *n1 = createNode(1000);  // Notice this is the max value
treenode *n2 = createNode(3);
treenode *n3 = createNode(2);

// Link them together:
n1->left = n2;
n1->right = n3;
```

In the first call you'll get into this line:

```
if (minimax(root->left)->value > minimax(root->right)->value)
    return root->left;
```

In the two recursive calls you get into this line:

```
if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    return root;
```

Consequently, the first call is actually the same as:

```
if (root->left->value > root->right->value)
    return root->left;
```

So you never ever checks the value of the root node. Therefore your code will give the result `3` but the correct result is `1000`.

To solve it make sure to check the value of the root node as well.

BTW:

An even more simple test (that fails) is:

```
treenode *n1 = createNode(1000);  // Notice this is the max value
treenode *n2 = createNode(3);

// Link them together:
n1->left = n2;
```

Comment: So I should add a `if(root > minimax(root->left)->value && root > minimax(root->right)->value) { return root; }` to check the root

Comment: @PilkeySEK Give it a try... Start with a simple cases like mine. If it works go on and use more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

This says it returns the right child but returns the left child:

```
// If the biggest value in the right child is greater than the biggest value in the left child, return the right child:
if (minimax(root->right)->value > minimax(root->left)->value)
    return root->left;
```

Comment: YES, im gonna edit that right now! Unfortunately, I tested it again, but it still only returns 3...

Comment: @PilkeySEK please don't make your question a moving target by modifying the posted code

Comment: @PilkeySEK: Editing a question to change it in a way that invalidates posted answers is inappropriate. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service, and you should not use a question as debugging session. You asked a question and got an answer.